# Working with ejs when using the script tag

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, express, ejs

I work in Node.js/Express + PostgreSQL and ejs.

I want to insert in tag script <%=result.dis%>. My result that I get from the DB query.

I trying to do something like this:

```
var vPlayer = `<%-JSON.stringify(avg.mark)%>`;
console.log(vPlayer);
```

Or this:

```
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerText = `<%=avg.mark %>`
console.log(div);
```

But it's don't worked. My full code where I want to draw a graph

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<% avg_t.rows.forEach(function(avg){%>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var vPlayer = `<%-JSON.stringify(avg.mark)%>`;
    console.log(vPlayer);

    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerText = `<%=avg.mark %>`
    console.log(div);

    google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['corechart']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
      data.addRows([
        ['Mushrooms', vPlayer],
        ['Mu112', div],
        ['Onions', 1],
      ]);
      var barchart_options = {
        title: 'Barchart: How Much Pizza I Ate Last 
        Night ',width:400,height:300,legend: '
        none '};
        var barchart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barchart_div'));
        barchart.draw(data, barchart_options);
      }
  </script>
<%} ) %>
```

Comment: Don't you think that you should assign `avg_t.rows` to a js variable and loop over it inside of the script tag.  Additionally, I think there is a problem passing this as string `<%-JSON.stringify(avg.mark)%>` you should parse it and then pass that js object here `['Mushrooms', vPlayer]`

Comment: @Ele Can you show me a small example, please ? I really need it but I can't figure it out myself...

Comment: @Ele Sorry for writing again. I just really need it. I can't figure out how to solve the problem myself....

Answer (score 0):

There are two lines I don't understand at all, but you're the owner of this code:

```
['Mushrooms', vPlayer /*I don't understand this*/],
['Mu112', div/*I don't understand this*/],
```

---

New approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  let rows = JSON.parse('<%= JSON.stringify(avg_t.rows) %>');
  let players = [];

  rows.forEach(function(avg, i) {
    players.push(avg.mark);

    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerText = avg.mark; //I don't know 
    div.setAttribute("id", `barchart_div${i}`);
    /*You should append this new div into a specific element*/
  });

  google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['corechart']
  });

  function drawChart() {
    players.forEach(function(vPlayer, i) {
      let div = document.getElementById(`barchart_div${i}`);
      let data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
      data.addRows([
        ['Mushrooms', vPlayer /*I don't understand this*/],
        ['Mu112', div/*I don't understand this*/],
        ['Onions', 1],
      ]);
      var barchart_options = {
        title: 'Barchart: How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night ',
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        legend: 'none'
      };
      var barchart = new google.visualization.BarChart(div);
      barchart.draw(data, barchart_options);
    });
  }

  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
</script>
```